# Problema con Apache xamp php (fuera de red local)

Tags: php, base-de-datos, apache, xampp

Estoy intentando hacer un servidor web fuera de red local en una máquina virtual, le instalé xampp y NoIP, en dicho servidor estoy programando las páginas en PHP de manera muy simple, haciendo una conexión a la BBDD, el usuario desde la interfaz web puede lograr iniciar sesión, el problema está en que cuando programo el registro del usuario no consigo lograr registrar los datos en la BBDD. (teniendo en cuenta que en la página de registro no me aparece ningún error de sintaxis.) No se que podría estar fallando para que no me deje registrar los datos.

> Conexión a BBDD

```
<?php

$cn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "BBDD");

if($cn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falló la conexion a la base de datos";
}

return $cn;

?>
```

> Código de registro

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_registro'])){
  include 'cn.php';
  $name = $cn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
  $email = $cn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $username = $cn->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

  $queryuser = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
  $queryemail = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";

  if ($resultuser = $cn->query($queryuser)) {
    $numerouser = $resultuser->num_rows;
  }

  if ($resultemail = $cn->query($queryemail)) {
    $numeroemail = $resultemail->num_rows;
  }

  if ($numeroemail > 0) {
    echo "<center>Este correo ya está registrado. Por favor intentelo con otro.</center>";
  }elseif ($numerouser>0) {
    echo "<center>Este usuario ya está registrado.</center>";
  } else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (name,email,username,signup_date,last_ip) VALUES ('$name','$email','$username','now()','$ip')";
    if ($registro = $cn->query($query)) {
      echo "<center>Se ha registrado correctamente.</center>";
      header("Refresh: 3; URL=index.php");
    }else{
      echo "<center>Lo sentimos, ha ocurrido un error en el registro, intentelo de nuevo mas tarde.</center>";
    }
  }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si usas PHP 5, PHP 7 debes hacer la conexion a la BBDD de la siguiente manera:

```
 $conexion = mysqli_connect( '127.0.0.1', 'root','Pass','BBDD' ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
```

Consulta el siguiente [ENLACE](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php) donde podras ver diferentes variaciones para la conexion.

Tambien debes recordar que MySQL por defecto no permite conexiones remotas a la BBDD desde otro host. La variable SKIP_NETWORKING permite restringir conexiones desde otro servidor. Si está a ON quiere decir que NO permite atender conexiones externas. Si estuviera en valor OFF sí permitiría conexiones externas desde otros hosts.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%netwo%';
+—————–+——-+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+—————–+——-+
| skip_networking | OFF   |
+—————–+——-+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Por qué quitaste el parámetro que indica el nombre de la base de datos?

Comment: Gracias por la acotacion @BetaM, solo fue una omision involuntaria. Saludos!